# Return Array as response in SoapUI Mock servcice

Tags: groovy, mocking, soapui

I have to mock a soap webservice operation that returns string array as an output. I could only generate a string as an output from below script.
Any help is welcome.

```
//script
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

// An array from which county and city will be drawn randomly

    def countryArray = 
    ["ONE",
    "TWO",
    "THREE"
     ]

    context.countryArray=countryArray
```

--response definition

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:upm="http://xxxx">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <upm:signResponse>
         <upm:signReturn>${countryArray}</upm:signReturn>
      </upm:signResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: How do you intend to have an array in there?

Comment: Webservice response is a String array
 
eg.
Strng [] methodA()
{
 String [] response=new String[]{"ONE","TWO","THREE"};
 return response;
} 

i Need to mock the above method, so my mock method needs to output a string array.

Comment: Requirement is to output an array as the response of mocked soapui service method.